# How to get average rating of Fivestar fields for multiple nodes?

Tags: views, rating

I am creating a Property listing application where each property has fivestar voting enabled through user comments and each property belongs to certain location.
I am trying to create a aggregated view of Locations (I am providing field relation to connect it to Properties) and show average rating of all properties belonging to that location. I am not able to get right result. Please help.